# How to copy specific columns of data from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a copySheet script that copies data from one google sheet file to another. I use this for lookups in the destination file. It works great but I want to make some improvements.

- Change lastCol to get the last column in the sheet as with the rows.
- Copy only certain columns from the source (Columns A, D, E) and paste into the destination in order (Columns A, B, C)

I've tried playing around with the script to do this myself for both points but my knoweldge is limited and I haven't been able to get it working.

Here are some example files:

[Example - source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZpUmiZgQctER8-sTQnI5XNSzv_u9WtrEnfFnqbv6cdo)

[Example - destination (script)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nZ1NCsNzWrF1JGSFEbAmcUJj7q1HlJFt8kpqtA8NMnI)

This is the script:

```
  function copySheet()
{
  // Opens the spreadsheet where the data is stored
  var sourceTable = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1sp8XFuOAGEfakS_td0xEiX3birz5ckoHNKvzrLPGTOI"); // Source file
  var srcSheet = sourceTable.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // Inserts the data into the target file
  var targetTable = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1i77LO4W2paMraipyC_bgx09P7TAuL2cwEVCNxGnbjhs"); // Target file
  var tarSheet = targetTable.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // Gets the last row in the source file
  var lastRowSource = srcSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = "E";

  // Reads the source into an array
  var aSrc = srcSheet.getRange("A1:" + lastCol + lastRowSource).getValues();

  // Save src array to destination
  tarSheet.getRange("A1:" + lastCol + lastRowSource).setValues(aSrc);
  }
```

Comment: Hello, did your issue get solved? Remember that if you want to mark your question as solved you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) whatever answer provided a solution to your problem. If that's not the case and your issue is not solved, please consider explaining why that's not the case so that this community can help you.

Comment: It is now solved. I posted an answer of what worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested script works for me but is a bit slow to run. Because the source file is having values added to it frequently, I have a trigger setup in the destination file to run the script on open.

I'm using this script that is a bit quicker to run:

```
function copySheet() {
  // Opens the spreadsheet where the data is stored  
  var sourceTable = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1sp8XFuOAGEfakS_td0xEiX3birz5ckoHNKvzrLPGTOI"); // Source file  
  //Defines source sheet  
  var srcSheet = sourceTable.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  
  // Opens the destination spreadsheet  
  var targetTable = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1i77LO4W2paMraipyC_bgx09P7TAuL2cwEVCNxGnbjhs"); // Target file  
  //Defines destination target sheet  
  var tarSheet = targetTable.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  
  //Retrieves all values from source  
  var srcValues = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
  //For each row in source values,creates new array containing columns A(0), D(3) & E(4) inside of trimedValues array  
  var trimmedValues = srcValues.map(function(row) {
    return[row[0],row[3],row[4]];
  })  
  // Save trimmedValues array to destination  
  tarSheet.getRange(1, 1, trimmedValues.length, 3).setValues(trimmedValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last column with content by using [srcSheet.getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn). Beware, this will retrieve and index (a number) and not a letter, but you don't need to use `A1 notation` when calling [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)), so you can use this number to indicate which columns to get.

Considering what you want to do, though, I don't think this is useful to achieve your purpose.

In effect, you want to copy specifically columns A, D and E to your destination sheet, at columns A, B, C.

I reworked your code a bit so that it does what you want:

```
function copySheet() {
  // Opens the spreadsheet where the data is stored
  var sourceTable = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1sp8XFuOAGEfakS_td0xEiX3birz5ckoHNKvzrLPGTOI"); // Source file
  var srcSheet = sourceTable.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // Inserts the data into the target file
  var targetTable = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1e6Dqyv14Edwj7JUFjZsM72IOj8Gh4-tMyUV4iGa-x6Q"); // Target file
  var tarSheet = targetTable.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // Gets the last row in the source file
  var lastRowSource = srcSheet.getLastRow();
  var originColumns = [1, 4, 5]; // Column indexes to be copied (A, D, E)
  var destColumns = [1, 2, 3]; // Column indexes to copy to (A, B, C)

  // Loop through each column to copy:
  for(var i = 0; i < originColumns.length; i++) {
    var originColumn = originColumns[i]; // Origin column index
    var destColumn = destColumns[i]; // Destination column index
    var originRange = srcSheet.getRange(1, originColumn, lastRowSource); // Origin range to copy
    var destRange = tarSheet.getRange(1, destColumn, lastRowSource); // Destination range to be copied to
    var values = originRange.getValues(); // Getting values from origin column
    destRange.setValues(values); // Setting values to destination column
  }
}
```

In this code, the column indexes to be copied are defined in two arrays (variables `originColumns` and `destColumns`), and then a `for` loop is used to iterate through each origin and destination column (copying data from one to the other). This cannot be done in a more systematic way because the columns to be copied (A, D, E) don't follow a specific pattern.

I hope this is useful to you.

Comment: I tried running your reworked script but I'm getting this error: 
This action is not supported unless the ‘runtimeVersion’ is set to ‘DEPRECATED_ES5’ in the appsscript.json file.

Comment: To solve this, go to `View > Show manifest file` in your script. The file `appsscript.json` will appear. In this file, add the following property before the last "}": `"runtimeVersion": "DEPRECATED_ES5"` (if the property `runtimeVersion` already exists, just change its value to `DEPRECATED_ES5`). And don't forget the comma just after previous property!

Comment: This didn't work but changing the runtimeVersion to "STACKDRIVER" did. After doing this the script is working correctly. Thank you for your help. I have had issues with the script being quite slow though. This is an issue because I have set up a trigger to run on open because the source file is constantly being added to and I need to keep the data live. I'm using a different script now that seems to be quicker that I will post here.